# Wait for subprocess to print something to stdout, with Popen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I want to make a wrapper around an existing program to create a programmable interface. The idea is that I want to expose functions that will send the appropriate input to the subprocess, and return a value corresponding to the input of that process.

However, I don't know how to make my interface wait for the program to return something.

This is what I've done.

```py
class ProcessWrapper:
    def __init__(self, process):
        self.proc = process
    def communicate(self, message):
        self.proc.stdin.write(message)
        while True:
            result = self.proc.stdout.readlines()
            if result: return result
```

But this seems very ressource-demanding. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines` is a non-blocking function, meaning the loop will execute as fast as possible, instead of waiting for some output from the process.

What should be used here instead is `readline`, essentially the same function but blocking.

```py
    def communicate(self, message):
        self.proc.stdin.send(message)
        return self.proc.stdout.readline()
```